# Rewrite rule in .htaccess does not work as requested

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with REWRITE RULES on .htaccess.
I am trying to rewrite dynamic URL in static ones.

The website is a multilingual website. 
I have already created static urls for the selected languages as shown below

```
www.example.net/index.php?lang= de
www.example.net/de/
...and so on....
```

Now I need to rewrite an URL query like this:

```
www.example.net/de/player.php?Name=Gianfranco&Surname=Zola&id=468
```

to

```
www.example.net/de/spieler-Gianfranco-Zola-468.html
```

The rule I used is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^de/spieler-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /player.php?Name=$1&Surname=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

If I click on the link in order to reach the page related to Zola in German, the link dos not redirect me on the profile page requested, but in the same page where I clicked on the link.

The link shown in the browser is the right one
**www.example.net/de/spieler-Gianfranco-Zola-468.html**

but, as said above, I cannot view the details contained in the page player.php.

Comment: You are doing it terribly wrong. In order to manage beautiful URLs you need a routing system, which you can find in any modern PHP-framework. In Laravel, for example, you can solve your problem in 10 seconds: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#basic-routing

Comment: `([^-])` is only for one letter. Use `([^-]*)` or `([^-]+)` instead. `+` is for 1 and more, and `*` for 0 and more.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this ,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule de/spieler-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ player.php?Name=$1&Surname=$2&id=$3 [L,NC]
```

**Correction**:  `^` was the problem & I removed `'/'` slash in front of player.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule

```
 RewriteRule ^de/spieler-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^\.]*)\.html$ /player.php?Name=$1&Surname=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Or

```
RewriteRule ^de/spieler-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([0-9]*)\.html$ /player.php?Name=$1&Surname=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Newman, thanks for your answers. Now I am really confused. I do not have experience with apache and the rewrite rulse. Where shall I put this rules? Shall I put them in the main .htacccess or in .htaccess in the folder www.example.de/de?

Comment: @user4265789, You should put it to main .htaccess. Just replace rule from your question.